# Saving text fields values with provider in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a flutter application that have some pages which have many textfields. Every time I change page the values of the textfields are lost. Is it overkill to keep them by updating the provider every time the text changes? Is it possible to read them at the beginning and save them when the user changes page?

Comment: Can you please provide source code of what you try?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is why you are using a State Management like provider. every time when the user changes the `TextField` you can update your provider, something like this:

```
class TextFieldWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textFieldProvider = context.watch<TextFieldProvider>();

    return TextField(
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        textFieldProvider.updateTextField(newValue);
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Enter Text',
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Maybe you ask how should I update my TextField when going back to the page where my TextFields placed. I have to say: you can the value of your ProviderValue as initial value and the value of your TextField, and handle it when it is null or empty the TextField value is empty too, and when it is changed again your TextField will be updated.

If you had any questions I'm here.

Happy Coding...